# userscripts for greasemonkey to disable meta refresh html tag

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, greasemonkey, userscripts

```
(function() {

var allMetas, thisMeta, content, timeout, timeout_ms, url;

timeout = -1;
url = 'none';

allMetas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for (var i = 0; i < allMetas.length; i++) {
    thisMeta = allMetas[i];

    if (thisMeta.httpEquiv.match(/refresh/i)) {
        if (thisMeta.content.match(/[\D]/)) {
            content = thisMeta.content.split(';');
            timeout = content[0];

            url = thisMeta.content.match(/url=['"]?([^'"]+)['"]?$/i);
            url = RegExp.lastParen;
        }
    }
}

if (timeout >= 0) {
    var stopTimer = window.setTimeout("window.stop();", timeout_ms);
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        try {
            window.clearTimeout(stopTimer);
        } catch (ex) {}
        window.stop();
    }, true);
}

})();
```

This user script to use with greasemonkey/tampermonkey writed to disable meta refresh html tag.

- works on "htmlcodetutorial.com/document/autoforwardexample.html"
- not works on "moviesvids.blogspot.co.uk/" (onely getting blank page).

Need some help to know what wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: include your script header - maybe you did something wrong there, however, I see the site that works has a 5 second timeout and the one that doesn't has a 0 second timeout - also you never set the value of `timeout_ms`

Comment: code updated/uploaded on https://greasyfork.org/fr/scripts/16079-disable-autorefresh/code